# Get the current pattern that matched an http.HandleFunc

Tags: go

Is there a way to get the current route that triggered an `http.HandleFunc`? Maybe something like this?

```
http.HandleFunc("/foo/", serveFoo)
func serveFoo(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(http.CurrentRoute())
    // Should print "/foo/"
}
```

The reason I want to get the current route is because I find myself writing code like this often.

```
if req.URL.Path != "/some-route/" {
    http.NotFound(resp, req)
    return
}
// or
key := req.URL.Path[len("/some-other-route/"):]
```

It would be nice if the code was a bit more copy-pastable, modular, and DRY like this.

```
if req.URL.Path != http.CurrentRoute() {
    http.NotFound(resp, req)
    return
}
// or
key := req.URL.Path[http.CurrentRoute():]
```

This is really just a small thing, so I'd rather not bring a whole other dependency into my project (Gorilla Mux).

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is exactly what a router/mux package like Gorilla saves you from doing. Other than that, `r.URL.Path` provides that functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get the current route that matched, but it is possible to eliminate the duplicate code in your scenario. Write a handler that checks the path before calling through to another handler:

```
func HandleFuncExact(mux *http.ServeMux, pattern string, handler func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    mux.HandleFunc(pattern, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if req.URL.Path != pattern {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }
        handler(w, r)
    })
}
```

In your application, call the wrapper instead of HandlFunc:

```
HandleFuncExact(http.DefaultServeMux, "/some-route/", serveSomeRoute)
```

The function `serveSomeRoute` can assume that the path is exactly "/some-route/".